# Adding Active Directory Accounts to Groups in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am attempting to write a script that creates Active Directory accounts via Powershell, that allows users to enter groups as needed after pulling a list based on the location the user will be working in. However, I can't seem to actually succeed in adding the user to a group when utilizing variables - my code works outside of the larger scope of my script, and works without utilizing variables, so hoping someone might be able to point out a glaring flaw to my amateur self?

```
    $firstname = Read-Host "Enter user's first name"
    $lastname = Read-Host "Enter users's last name"
    
    $firstname_lowercase = $firstname.ToLower()
    $lastname_lowercase = $lastname.ToLower()
    
    $ad_username = ($firstname_lowercase + "." + $lastname_lowercase)

$ad_continue = Read-Host "Would you like to add the user to a Active Directory store group? (y/n)"
    
    while ($ad_continue -eq "y") {
        Write-Host "Please enter the group name you would like to add the user to:"
    
        Get-ADGroup -Filter 'Name -like $store_groupinitials' | Select -ExpandProperty Name
    
        echo ""
    
        $adgroup_add = Read-Host "Please enter the group name you would like to add the user to"
    
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $adgroup_add -Members $ad_username
    
        $ad_continue = Read-Host "Would you like to add user to another group? (y/n)"
        }
```

The error I receive is:

```
    Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'test1.test2' under: 'DC=hq,DC=domainhere,DC=com'.
At C:\Scripts\ad_google_create\google_ad_with_groups.ps1:114 char:3
+         Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $adgroup_add -Members $ad_username
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (test1.test2:ADPrincipal) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundExcepti
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.
   AddADGroupMember
```

It seems like maybe its only looking in the top level domain? When using my script, it does successfully create an account with the name test1.test2 in the expected OU, but the account never gets added as a member of said group. Hoping someone might be able to shed some light.

Comment: _"it does successfully create an account with the name test1.test2 in the expected OU"_... WHERE in this script is the new user created then?

Comment: First time posting to Stack Overflow, assumed a snippet of the whole script would work, but I am creating that account earlier in the script via New-ADUser -Name ($firstname + " " + $lastname) -SamAccountName $ad_username -AccountPassword $AD_password -ChangePasswordAtLogon 1 -DisplayName ($firstname + " " + $lastname) -EmailAddress $email -GivenName $firstname -Surname $lastname -Enabled 1 -Office $store_initials -Path $store_ou

Comment: because of the single quotes in `'Name -like $store_groupinitials'` variable `$store_groupinitials` will not get expanded (if that is defined somewhere..). Not only that, but the `-like` operator is used with wildcard characters. If not then use `-eq`

Comment: Welcome to SO, but you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70083010/edit) your question and put that vital information in with your code so we know what we're dealing with

Answer (score 0):

Learned a lot about what I need to specify when posting to SO, thanks everyone. Will post full (or at least vital pieces of code) next time. In the mean time, via r/powershell I was able to find out that I needed to specify a DC when creating a user account due to replication.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).